# What will the following print?

Tags: php

What will the following code print? 
print ‘’four’’ * 200;

Comment: Why not just try it?

Comment: He's testing us to see how knowledgeable we are before asking his real question

Comment: Why not read other questions and answers?  There's a ton of knowledge here.

Comment: I actually wanted to have a explanation for this, thanks for Conrad's comment. I needed to ask the question in a different manner ;-) Sorry Guys ;-)

Comment: The question is quite OK, it should just have read 'Why is "four" * 200 === 0 in PHP'

Comment: @Roland it's alright, we understand </lies> just be sure to ask the question you want the answer to.

Comment: @Roland if your satisfied with the question you should accept an answer by pressing the check mark below it's vote count.

Comment: Thanks, I'm quite new to this site ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it would print zero "0" indeed.  The thing is PHP will type cast the string value to an integer. This would result in 0 (Zero); and if you times any value with zero you'll get zero.

Good Question Roland!

Answer (score 7):

It prints "0"
[alt text http://mywebprogrammer.com/images/soAnswer.PNG](http://mywebprogrammer.com/images/soAnswer.PNG)

The result is to the left of the second line.

To see why this is you can do a quick test `echo (int)'four';` this will attempt to explicitly cast the string 'four' to an integer which since it is not an integer will technicaly fail, resulting in a 0 which of course is equal to FALSE.  If you replace the 'four' with '4', still a string, you can properly cast it to an integer and it will produce the result of 800 in the case of your example ("print '4' * 200").

Answer (score 4):

Since the string cannot be casted to a number, the multiplication with a string will result in 0.

Comment: Numeric strings can be casted to the integer they represent though.